# Css link style etiquette

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags, styles

Hi was wondering if it's better to style the menu's links of a page in a web application styling only the *a* tag or the *li* tags or both.

Example:

```
<ul id="mainMenu">
<li><a href="">myLink</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want it to be colored green, is it better to style the color green on the *a* tag or the *li*?
Considering i will mostly use js to interact with php and everything else, is it bad to not add the *a* tags at all and just stick to the *li* tags to trigger the js functions?(it will mostly be ajax and dynamic content).

Thanks

Comment: Generally people feel uncomfortable when they see a link, click it, and it takes them nowhere. If your links don't go anywhere, make sure they look as distinct from traditional links as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hi was wondering if it's better to style the menu's links of a page in a web application styling only the a tag or the li tags or both.

Well, that depends on what kind of formatting you want for your site navigation (or other list use) since style properties will behaviour differently between the two elements.

An obvious example is the default values from some properties like `display`.The default value for link `<a>` tags is `display:inline` and the list `li` tag will have `display:list-item` as default style so setting something like:

```
li {background-color: red;}
```

will differ from

```
a { background-color:blue;}
```

You can see a functional [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunovieira/qawGJ/) that intents to show the space occupied of both tags.

> is it bad to not add the a tags at all and just stick to the li tags to trigger the js functions?

The a tags have already some properties that made them more user friendly. For example, if your user already visited a site, you can style your a tag using the pseudo-selector `:visited`. You can do this in a easy way with your `<li>` elements. Also, a tags already have the `cursor` property set as `pointer` when hover and even if you can use this in your list elements you would use more css to do the same thing the `a` tag has as default.

My final piece of advise, use `lists` elements to style the internal position of your  navigation links and use the links to associate js functions and to style your navigation rules, like when a link is visited, when a link is active and so on.

I hope it helped. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the thing is that styling the container(in this case the <li>) and not even using the a tags feels like making the code much easier when things start getting confused; i made a other web applications and always used to style the <a> tag and, if needed, his container but at some point(when lots of js and style changes are involved) things always became quite hard to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

`a` tags have default styles that give them colour and usually an underline. Therefore, if you want to override those styles you must apply them to the `a` itself, not the `li` containing it.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you do not want to color the entire `tag`.
It would become messy when changes are there, or when the project expands.

So, instead of

```
li {
    /*Your styles here*/
    /*this is not a great method*/
}
```

you might want to add some reference to it.
So your html like,

```
<ul class="someclass">
    <li>
         <a>This is a link</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and thus, css like

```
ul.someclass li {
    /*Your styles here */
}
```

Now, in the above example styles, the confusion whether to apply styles to the parent element (`<li>`) or the children elements (`<a>`).

The child element would inherit properties from it's parent elements.

So in case most of your children elements have most properties same as it's parent, apply the styles to the parent.

In case there is some style which you need only for the child element, just add THAT style to the child element.

Example  (HTML Above):

```
ul.someclass li {
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
ul.someclass li a {
    color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Um... The UL already has an ID to give context, it doen't need a class as well.

Comment: I'm giving a generic way of writing css, assuming the OP wanted focus on writing css, not specifically of the id present in the HTML provided.

Answer (score 0):

I would say do something like:

```
 ul#mainMenu li a{
      your style
 }
```

This way you are applying style to the links in that menu and not messing with links you may add in the future.

Comment: `ul#mainMenu` is redundant, since there can only be one element with the ID `mainMenu` on the page.

Comment: @Kolink, it does change the /specificity/ of the selector, so it's not wholly redundant

Comment: Not really, since the ID is the highest specificity possible.

Comment: @Kolink Not necessarily. 1) It gives context. We know we're styling an unordered list. 2) The stylesheet could be used on multiple pages. It may be that `#mainMenu` is not a `ul` on another page.

Comment: #1 is usually why I do this.  It makes the CSS file a bit more readable (for me at least), even if you don't run into the issue in #2.

Comment: would ul#mainMenu perform differently (slower) than #mainMenu?

Answer (score 0):

your a tag will always override the color property of your parent element in this case li. That said you need to style both for different properties like display for li's and color of a tags. Your layout is perfectly valid.